# What does the forceRefresh parameter do in a method that only calls await Task.FromResult(items)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to create a Xamarin Forms application that's based off the Tabbed Page template provided by Visual Studio.  When reviewing the code in the template, they use a generic `IDataStore<T>` interface to define the following method:

```
public interface IDataStore<T> {
Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false); }
```

Then they define the `MockDataStore` class which implements the `IDataStore<Item>` interface in the following way:

```
public class MockDataStore : IDataStore<Item> {
    readonly List<Item> items;

    public MockDataStore() {
        items = new List<Item>() { 
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "First item", Description="This is an item description." },
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Second item", Description="This is an item description." } } 
};

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false) => await Task.FromResult(items);
```

I have no idea what the `forceRefresh` parameter is doing.  I know they call `GetItemsAsync` with an empty parameter list and call it once with `true` as a parameter.  I can't find any documentation on MSDN regarding the `forceRefresh` used in the `Task.FromResults` method.

The `Item` class is nothing special, it's a standard public class with three public string auto-implemented get/set properties named `Id`, `Text`, and `Description`.

This is a Xamarin Forms template so they register the `MockDataStore` class as a Dependency Service when they start the app, and they only reference the methods through a public get-only instance of the `IDataStore<Item>` like so:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public IDataStore<Item> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<Item>>();
```

Then in a load command method they reference the `GetItemsAsync` call:

```
var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
```

My guess is that if `forceRefresh` is false, the call to get the items won't actually occur if certain circumstances are true, like if the items passed to `Task.FromResult(items)` is not null, for example.  I don't know if the `forceRefresh` relates to the mobile phone's refresh indicator for the list view, or if it's only referring to refreshing the items list itself.

Any clarification or references that someone could provide would be helpful. And if you need any additional information from me to help find an answer (which I expect you will, as this is my first posting), I will be happy to edit the question and provide that.

Comment: `public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false) =>` In that specific instance, the `forceRefresh` parameter does **absolutely nothing**.

Comment: The `forceRefresh` approach is _often_ used when the cost of retrieving data is expensive - thus there is some form of cache involved. When `forceRefresh` is passed as `true` it basically means 'bypass the cache, and go get me the real data please'. Note, that is **not** what it is doing here (in this code the parameter is ignored). I am merely pointing out what a parameter of that name _usually_ is used for.

Comment: Do **any** of the implementations of `IDataStore<Item>` actually use the parameter?

Comment: @mjwills There are no other implementations of `IDataStore<T>` at all.  It's from the built-in Visual Studio template so maybe they were just putting it in to show how it could be used in another implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forceRefresh` in this context doesn't do anything.

It is likely that the `real` class which implements `IDataStore<Item>` uses `forceRefresh` uses it to make the method *not* return the cached values and fetch fresh data.

This technique is used when fetching fresh data takes too long to do it on each call. The time (or CPU) may be needed to make a web request or calculate something. Another scenario is that refreshing data may not work all the time, and a local, even stale, copy may be better than not having anything at all.

Here is a an example with an artificial delay.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false) 
{
    if( cache == null || forceRefresh == true)
    {
        // Simulate a long call (an web api request, for example)
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        cache = new List<Item>{new Item() {Name = "One"}, new Item() {Name = "One"}};
    }

    return cache;
}
```

---

## Example

### Code

```
public interface IDataStore<T>{ Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false); }

public class DataStore : IDataStore<string>
{
    List<string> cache;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        if (cache == null || forceRefresh == true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // Simulate a long call
            cache = new List<string> { "One", "Two" };
        }

        return cache;
    }

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var dataStore = new DataStore();

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await dataStore.GetItemsAsync(); //Slow
        Console.WriteLine($"Call {i++} took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        sw.Restart();
        await dataStore.GetItemsAsync(); //Fast
        Console.WriteLine($"Call {i++} took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");


        sw.Restart();
        await dataStore.GetItemsAsync(forceRefresh: true); //Fast
        Console.WriteLine($"Call {i++} took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Call 0 took 2021ms
Call 1 took 0ms
Call 2 took 2004ms
```